# declarativeWebRequest and hosts rules

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to update my extension to manifest version 2.0 now. As I was using the `webRequest` API, and I need to change it to `declarativeWebRequest`.

The problem is that I am having a problem with the permissions.

```
To execute the action "declarativeWebRequest.SetRequestHeader",
you need to request host permission for all hosts.
```

And my manifest looks like:

```
"permissions": [
    "declarativeWebRequest",
    "https://example.com/default.dll"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

And my background page looks like this:

```
var request_matcher = new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher({
    url: {
        urlEquals: "https://example.com/default.dll"
    },
    resourceType: ["main_frame"],
    stages: ['onBeforeSendHeaders']
});
var request_rule = {
    conditions: [request_matcher],
    actions: [
        new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.SetRequestHeader({
            name: "User-Agent",
            value: "New user agent "
        })
    ]
};
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.addRules([
    request_rule
]);
```

If I change the permission to:

```
"permissions": [
    "declarativeWebRequest",
    "https://*/*"
],
```

Everything runs. However, I do not believe this is the correct way to work. Should I even ask permission to ALL SITES if I need to just work with a single page or domain?

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a minimal self-contained example in your question which reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is your Chrome version? I'm thinking about be a issue on Beta for Windows (28.0.1500.52).

Comment: 27.0.1453.110 Beta on Linux. Have you already created a self-contained example? Perhaps my way of testing differs from what you actually intended.

Comment: Here, [**itau-dev.rar**](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D1579974_63304576_425122). It's my extension called [**Itaú Dev**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ita%C3%BA-dev/kilnjdldofoaiolmphahopaghanpjlpl). Just load it and open the `_generated_background_page.html`, go to **Console** tab. On `beta`, at least, you can see this issue.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 30.

Comment: Do you think that it is an issue?

Comment: Probably yes. Go open a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/. Meanwhile, to solve your question, don't switch to the `webRequest` API. It's not mandatory. You can just use a background page instead of an event page (which is fully valid, even with manifest v2), which allows you to stick to the `webRequest` API.

Answer (score 0):

I known this issue.

```
"permissions": [
    "declarativeWebRequest",
    "*://*/*"
],
```

Salut.